# silverlight mpeg-4

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mpeg-4

im currently working on a project, where I need to create a web video player. At the current state, my app plays recordings provided by client as motion JPEG and H264/AVC. 
The thing is, he also wants MPEG-4 part 2 (Visual), which i call mp4v. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page, mp4v is supported, but i can't get any sample to work with Silverlight. Even if this encoding is not supported by Silverlight, can I get my app to display this recordings without converting them? Is there any way to get this to work?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The MSDN page you are referring to states that MPEG-4 Part 2 is only supported on Silverlight for Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they are Mpeg Part 2? Have you tried just calling them MP4?

If the encode isn't supported by Silverlight, you would have to re-encode them....sorry...