# Playing mp4v file in Silverlight5

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight5 based application which works in both In Browser as well as OOB mode.
I need to play video files which are of mp4 extension and encoding as shown by VLC media player:

Stream 0
       Type: Video
       Codec: MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)
       Resolution: 320*240
       Frame Rate: 10
       Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV.

I have tried using the Media Element provided by Silverlight framework and also tried using the Azure media services to display the video, but did not have any success. It says that the file format is not supported.

Will really appreciate your inputs.

Alpee

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304934/silverlight-mpeg-4

Answer (score 1):

Windows does support MPEG4 video decoder. See below links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819502(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819503(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) a free tool to check the codec info in each stream inside a media container.

Without examining files it is hard to tell what's wrong.